# Some values work with rsa encryption/decryption but some dont

Tags: python, rsa

I have created a program in python to encrypt in decrypt using the RSA algorithm but it dosent work for all values

i have use (p, q, n, phi(n), e, d) = (1033, 5039, 5205287, 5199216, 7, 4456471)

```
#this is the encryption part
def RSA():
    global D
    L = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",' ','!','?','(',')','/','.',',',"'"]
    N = ["01",'02',"03","04","05",'06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35']
    C = ""
    M = input("Message to encrypt: ")
    for l in M:
        A = L.index(l)
        B = N[A]
        C += B
        D = "1" + C
    print(D)
    def main1():
        n = 5205287
        e = 7
        EN = (int(D)**e) % n
        print(EN)
    main1()
    A = input()
    if A == "a":
        RSA()
RSA()


#ignore the first part of the code
```

Only some numbers work and i get the proper decryption but some other i get tottaly different numbers

Comment: Which values work? Which don't?

Comment: It seems that values larger then about 4500000 start to decrypt to wrong values